# Cannot get the body of email with Gmail PHP API

Tags: php, gmail-api

I'm having trouble with the Gmail PHP API.

I want to retrieve the body content of emails, but I can retrieve it only for emails which have attachments! My question is why?

Here's my code so far:

```
// Authentication things above...
$client = getClient();
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);    
$list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['maxResults' => 1000]);

while ($list->getMessages() != null) {   
    foreach ($list->getMessages() as $mlist) {               
        $message_id = $mlist->id;   
        $optParamsGet2['format'] = 'full';
        $single_message = $gmail->users_messages->get('me', $message_id, $optParamsGet2);

        $threadId = $single_message->getThreadId();
        $payload = $single_message->getPayload();
        $headers = $payload->getHeaders();
        $parts = $payload->getParts();
        //print_r($parts); PRINTS SOMETHING ONLY IF I HAVE ATTACHMENTS...
        $body = $parts[0]['body'];
        $rawData = $body->data;
        $sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
        $decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData); //should display my body content
    }

    if ($list->getNextPageToken() != null) {
        $pageToken = $list->getNextPageToken();
        $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['pageToken' => $pageToken, 'maxResults' => 1000]);
    } else {
        break;
    }
}
```

The second option to retrieve content that I know is by using the snippet located in the **Headers** part, but it only retrieves the 50 first characters or so, which isn't very useful.

Comment: Can anybody help me. Im using this url $endpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/$id?format=full"; but its only getting 194 characters in an email not the full email. what can i do?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Let's do a little experiment. I've sent two messages to myself. One with an attachment, and one without.

**Request:**

```
GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages?maxResults=2
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "messages": [
  {
   "id": "14fe21fd6b3fb46f",
   "threadId": "14fe21fd6b3fb46f"
  },
  {
   "id": "14fe21f9341ed73c",
   "threadId": "14fe21f9341ed73c"
  }
 ],
 "nextPageToken": "08943597140129624594",
 "resultSizeEstimate": 3
}
```

I only ask for the payload, since that is where all the relevant parts are:

```
fields = payload

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14fe21fd6b3fb46f?fields=payload

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14fe21f9341ed73c?fields=payload
```

**Mail without attachment:**

```
{
 "payload": {
  "parts": [
   {
    "partId": "0",
    "mimeType": "text/plain",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "size": 22,
     "data": "aGVjaz8gTm8gYXR0YWNobWVudD8NCg=="
    }
   },
   {
    "partId": "1",
    "mimeType": "text/html",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "size": 43,
     "data": "PGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI-aGVjaz8gTm8gYXR0YWNobWVudD88L2Rpdj4NCg=="
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

**Mail with attachment:**

```
{
 "payload": {
  "parts": [
   {
    "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "multipart/alternative; boundary=001a1142e23c551e8e05200b4be0"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "size": 0
    },
    "parts": [
     {
      "partId": "0.0",
      "mimeType": "text/plain",
      "filename": "",
      "headers": [
       {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
       }
      ],
      "body": {
       "size": 9,
       "data": "V293IG1hbg0K"
      }
     },
     {
      "partId": "0.1",
      "mimeType": "text/html",
      "filename": "",
      "headers": [
       {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
       }
      ],
      "body": {
       "size": 30,
       "data": "PGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI-V293IG1hbjwvZGl2Pg0K"
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "partId": "1",
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
    "filename": "feelthebern.jpg",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "image/jpeg; name=\"feelthebern.jpg\""
     },
     {
      "name": "Content-Disposition",
      "value": "attachment; filename=\"feelthebern.jpg\""
     },
     {
      "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
      "value": "base64"
     },
     {
      "name": "X-Attachment-Id",
      "value": "f_ieq3ev0i0"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "attachmentId": "ANGjdJ_2xG3WOiLh6MbUdYy4vo2VhV2kOso5AyuJW3333rbmk8BIE1GJHIOXkNIVGiphP3fGe7iuIl_MGzXBGNGvNslwlz8hOkvJZg2DaasVZsdVFT_5JGvJOLefgaSL4hqKJgtzOZG9K1XSMrRQAtz2V0NX7puPdXDU4gvalSuMRGwBhr_oDSfx2xljHEbGG6I4VLeLZfrzGGKW7BF-GO_FUxzJR8SizRYqIhgZNA6PfRGyOhf1s7bAPNW3M9KqWRgaK07WTOYl7DzW4hpNBPA4jrl7tgsssExHpfviFL7yL52lxsmbsiLe81Z5UoM",
     "size": 100446
    }
   }
  ]
 }
}
```

These responses corresponds to the `$parts` in your code. As you can see, if you are lucky, `$parts[0]['body']->data` will give you what you want, but most of the time it will not.

There are generally two approaches to this problem. You could implement the following algorithm (you are much better at PHP than me, but this is the general outline of it):

1. Traverse the `payload.parts` and check if it contains a `part` that has the body you were looking for (either `text/plain` or `text/html`). If it has, you are done with your searching. If you were parsing a mail like the one above with no attachment, this would be enough.
2. Do step 1 again, but this time with the `parts` found inside the `parts` you just checked, recursively. You will eventually find your `part`. If you were parsing a mail like the one above with an attachment, this would eventually find you your `body`.

The algorithm could look something like the following (example in JavaScript):

```js
var response = {
 "payload": {
  "parts": [
   {
    "mimeType": "multipart/alternative",
    "filename": "",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "multipart/alternative; boundary=001a1142e23c551e8e05200b4be0"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "size": 0
    },
    "parts": [
     {
      "partId": "0.0",
      "mimeType": "text/plain",
      "filename": "",
      "headers": [
       {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "text/plain; charset=UTF-8"
       }
      ],
      "body": {
       "size": 9,
       "data": "V293IG1hbg0K"
      }
     },
     {
      "partId": "0.1",
      "mimeType": "text/html",
      "filename": "",
      "headers": [
       {
        "name": "Content-Type",
        "value": "text/html; charset=UTF-8"
       }
      ],
      "body": {
       "size": 30,
       "data": "PGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI-V293IG1hbjwvZGl2Pg0K"
      }
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "partId": "1",
    "mimeType": "image/jpeg",
    "filename": "feelthebern.jpg",
    "headers": [
     {
      "name": "Content-Type",
      "value": "image/jpeg; name=\"feelthebern.jpg\""
     },
     {
      "name": "Content-Disposition",
      "value": "attachment; filename=\"feelthebern.jpg\""
     },
     {
      "name": "Content-Transfer-Encoding",
      "value": "base64"
     },
     {
      "name": "X-Attachment-Id",
      "value": "f_ieq3ev0i0"
     }
    ],
    "body": {
     "attachmentId": "ANGjdJ_2xG3WOiLh6MbUdYy4vo2VhV2kOso5AyuJW3333rbmk8BIE1GJHIOXkNIVGiphP3fGe7iuIl_MGzXBGNGvNslwlz8hOkvJZg2DaasVZsdVFT_5JGvJOLefgaSL4hqKJgtzOZG9K1XSMrRQAtz2V0NX7puPdXDU4gvalSuMRGwBhr_oDSfx2xljHEbGG6I4VLeLZfrzGGKW7BF-GO_FUxzJR8SizRYqIhgZNA6PfRGyOhf1s7bAPNW3M9KqWRgaK07WTOYl7DzW4hpNBPA4jrl7tgsssExHpfviFL7yL52lxsmbsiLe81Z5UoM",
     "size": 100446
    }
   }
  ]
 }
};

// In e.g. a plain text message, the payload is the only part.
var parts = [response.payload];

while (parts.length) {
  var part = parts.shift();
  if (part.parts) {
    parts = parts.concat(part.parts);
  }

  if(part.mimeType === 'text/html') {
    var decodedPart = decodeURIComponent(escape(atob(part.body.data.replace(/\-/g, '+').replace(/\_/g, '/'))));
    console.log(decodedPart);
  }
}
```

The far easier option is to just get the raw data of the mail, and let a already written library do the work for you:

**Request:**

```
format = raw
fields = raw

GET https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/14fe21fd6b3fb46f?format=raw&fields=raw
```

**Response:**

```
{
 "raw": "TUlNRS1WZXJzaW9uOiAxLjANClJlY2VpdmVkOiBieSAxMC4yOC45OS4xOTYgd2l0aCBIVFRQOyBGcmksIDE4IFNlcCAyMDE1IDEzOjIzOjAxIC0wNzAwIChQRFQpDQpEYXRlOiBGcmksIDE4IFNlcCAyMDE1IDIyOjIzOjAxICswMjAwDQpEZWxpdmVyZWQtVG86IGVtdGhvbGluQGdtYWlsLmNvbQ0KTWVzc2FnZS1JRDogPENBRHNaTFJ5eGk2UGt0MHZnUS1iZHd1N2FNLWNHRmZKcEwrRHYyb3ZKOGp4SGN4VWhfQUBtYWlsLmdtYWlsLmNvbT4NClN1YmplY3Q6IFdoYXQgZGENCkZyb206IEVtaWwgVGhvbGluIDxlbXRob2xpbkBnbWFpbC5jb20-DQpUbzogRW1pbCBUaG9saW4gPGVtdGhvbGluQGdtYWlsLmNvbT4NCkNvbnRlbnQtVHlwZTogbXVsdGlwYXJ0L2FsdGVybmF0aXZlOyBib3VuZGFyeT0wMDFhMTE0NjhmMTY1YzUwNDUwNTIwMGI0YzYxDQoNCi0tMDAxYTExNDY4ZjE2NWM1MDQ1MDUyMDBiNGM2MQ0KQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L3BsYWluOyBjaGFyc2V0PVVURi04DQoNCmhlY2s_IE5vIGF0dGFjaG1lbnQ_DQoNCi0tMDAxYTExNDY4ZjE2NWM1MDQ1MDUyMDBiNGM2MQ0KQ29udGVudC1UeXBlOiB0ZXh0L2h0bWw7IGNoYXJzZXQ9VVRGLTgNCg0KPGRpdiBkaXI9Imx0ciI-aGVjaz8gTm8gYXR0YWNobWVudD88L2Rpdj4NCg0KLS0wMDFhMTE0NjhmMTY1YzUwNDUwNTIwMGI0YzYxLS0="
}
```

The biggest drawback of the second method is that if you get the message raw, you will download all the attachment data right away, which might be far to much data for your use case.

I'm not good at PHP, but [this](https://github.com/php-mime-mail-parser/php-mime-mail-parser) looks promising if you want to go with the second solution! Good luck!

Comment: Amazing! Thanks a lot for the founding! I'll go for the for the first method next monday and paste the full code for future users.

Comment: @F3L1X79 No problem :) Glad I could help. Looking forward to seeing the code!

Comment: I'm dealing with this issue for few days.. you just saved my day. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @尤川豪 Glad to hear that :) No problem!

Comment: Just for information, the final code to retrieve the content is written on my own answer (tested and approved).

Comment: @Tholle Thanks for this extensive answer. The while loop returns 'undefined' for the decodedPart everytime feed it with a mail payload, because I am getting undefined for parts.length. parts, being the payload here, is an object right, not an array? Any ideas?

Comment: @ffritz No problem ffritz. Are you putting the payload in an array? I.e. `var parts = [response.payload];`, not `var parts = payload;`?

Comment: @Tholle I see, thanks! Didn't realize I have to actually put it into an array as I thought it already was. Works like a charm now.

Comment: Can anybody help me. Im using this url $endpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/$id?format=full"; but its only getting 194 characters in an email not the full email. what can i do?

Answer (score 28):

***UPDATE: You might want to check my second answer below this one for a more complete code.***

Finally, I worked today, so here's the complete code answer for finding the body - thanks to **@Tholle**:

```
// Authentication things above
/*
 * Decode the body.
 * @param : encoded body  - or null
 * @return : the body if found, else FALSE;
 */
function decodeBody($body) {
    $rawData = $body;
    $sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
    $decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);
    if(!$decodedMessage){
        $decodedMessage = FALSE;
    }
    return $decodedMessage;
}

$client = getClient();
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

$list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['maxResults' => 1000]);

try{
    while ($list->getMessages() != null) {

        foreach ($list->getMessages() as $mlist) {

            $message_id = $mlist->id;
            $optParamsGet2['format'] = 'full';
            $single_message = $gmail->users_messages->get('me', $message_id, $optParamsGet2);
            $payload = $single_message->getPayload();

            // With no attachment, the payload might be directly in the body, encoded.
            $body = $payload->getBody();
            $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($body['data']);

            // If we didn't find a body, let's look for the parts
            if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
                $parts = $payload->getParts();
                foreach ($parts  as $part) {
                    if($part['body']) {
                        $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($part['body']->data);
                        break;
                    }
                    // Last try: if we didn't find the body in the first parts, 
                    // let's loop into the parts of the parts (as @Tholle suggested).
                    if($part['parts'] && !$FOUND_BODY) {
                        foreach ($part['parts'] as $p) {
                            // replace 'text/html' by 'text/plain' if you prefer
                            if($p['mimeType'] === 'text/html' && $p['body']) {
                                $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($p['body']->data);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if($FOUND_BODY) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Finally, print the message ID and the body
            print_r($message_id . " : " . $FOUND_BODY);
        }

        if ($list->getNextPageToken() != null) {
            $pageToken = $list->getNextPageToken();
            $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['pageToken' => $pageToken, 'maxResults' => 1000]);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

As you can see, my problem was, sometimes the body cannot be found in the **payload->parts** but directly in the **payload->body**! (plus I add the loop for multiple parts).

Hope this helps somebody else.

Comment: That's interesting, do you know what the condition is for the body to be in payload -> body instead of in payload -> parts?

Comment: @guival, not sure, but if I remember correctly it depends if your mail got attachments or not. It's been a long time since I need to use this script, sorry.

Comment: @F3L1X79 ok thanks, what I've figured out so far is that if the payload `mimeType` is `multipart/alternative`, the body will be in payload parts, and if the `mimeType` is `text/plain` or `text/html` the body will be in payload body. I haven't tested attachments yet, but I'll lookout for them

Comment: Can anybody help me. Im using this url $endpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/$id?format=full"; but its only getting 194 characters in an email not the full email. what can i do?

Comment: The code should be recursive, please see https://stackoverflow.com/a/54139473/439944

Answer (score 22):

For those who are interested I greatly improved my last answer, making it working with text/html (and fallback to text/plain if necessary) and transforming the images as base64 attachments that will auto-load when printed as full HTML!

Code isn't perfect at all and is way too long to explain in details but it's working for me.

Feel free to take it and adapt it (maybe correct/improve it if necessary).

```
// Authentication things above
/*
 * Decode the body.
 * @param : encoded body  - or null
 * @return : the body if found, else FALSE;
 */
function decodeBody($body) {
    $rawData = $body;
    $sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
    $decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);
    if(!$decodedMessage){
        $decodedMessage = FALSE;
    }
    return $decodedMessage;
}

$client = getClient();
$gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);

$list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['maxResults' => 1000]);

try{
    while ($list->getMessages() != null) {

        foreach ($list->getMessages() as $mlist) {

            $message_id = $mlist->id;
            $optParamsGet2['format'] = 'full';
            $single_message = $gmail->users_messages->get('me', $message_id, $optParamsGet2);
            $payload = $single_message->getPayload();
            $parts = $payload->getParts();
            // With no attachment, the payload might be directly in the body, encoded.
            $body = $payload->getBody();
            $FOUND_BODY = FALSE;
            // If we didn't find a body, let's look for the parts
            if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
                foreach ($parts  as $part) {
                    if($part['parts'] && !$FOUND_BODY) {
                        foreach ($part['parts'] as $p) {
                            if($p['parts'] && count($p['parts']) > 0){
                                foreach ($p['parts'] as $y) {
                                    if(($y['mimeType'] === 'text/html') && $y['body']) {
                                        $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($y['body']->data);
                                        break;
                                    }
                                }
                            } else if(($p['mimeType'] === 'text/html') && $p['body']) {
                                $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($p['body']->data);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if($FOUND_BODY) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // let's save all the images linked to the mail's body:
            if($FOUND_BODY && count($parts) > 1){
                $images_linked = array();
                foreach ($parts  as $part) {
                    if($part['filename']){
                        array_push($images_linked, $part);
                    } else{
                        if($part['parts']) {
                            foreach ($part['parts'] as $p) {
                                if($p['parts'] && count($p['parts']) > 0){
                                    foreach ($p['parts'] as $y) {
                                        if(($y['mimeType'] === 'text/html') && $y['body']) {
                                            array_push($images_linked, $y);
                                        }
                                    }
                                } else if(($p['mimeType'] !== 'text/html') && $p['body']) {
                                    array_push($images_linked, $p);
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
                // special case for the wdcid...
                preg_match_all('/wdcid(.*)"/Uims', $FOUND_BODY, $wdmatches);
                if(count($wdmatches)) {
                    $z = 0;
                    foreach($wdmatches[0] as $match) {
                        $z++;
                        if($z > 9){
                            $FOUND_BODY = str_replace($match, 'image0' . $z . '@', $FOUND_BODY);
                        } else {
                            $FOUND_BODY = str_replace($match, 'image00' . $z . '@', $FOUND_BODY);
                        }
                    }
                }
                preg_match_all('/src="cid:(.*)"/Uims', $FOUND_BODY, $matches);
                if(count($matches)) {
                    $search = array();
                    $replace = array();
                    // let's trasnform the CIDs as base64 attachements 
                    foreach($matches[1] as $match) {
                        foreach($images_linked as $img_linked) {
                            foreach($img_linked['headers'] as $img_lnk) {
                                if( $img_lnk['name'] === 'Content-ID' || $img_lnk['name'] === 'Content-Id' || $img_lnk['name'] === 'X-Attachment-Id'){
                                    if ($match === str_replace('>', '', str_replace('<', '', $img_lnk->value)) 
                                            || explode("@", $match)[0] === explode(".", $img_linked->filename)[0]
                                            || explode("@", $match)[0] === $img_linked->filename){
                                        $search = "src=\"cid:$match\"";
                                        $mimetype = $img_linked->mimeType;
                                        $attachment = $gmail->users_messages_attachments->get('me', $mlist->id, $img_linked['body']->attachmentId);
                                        $data64 = strtr($attachment->getData(), array('-' => '+', '_' => '/'));
                                        $replace = "src=\"data:" . $mimetype . ";base64," . $data64 . "\"";
                                        $FOUND_BODY = str_replace($search, $replace, $FOUND_BODY);
                                    }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
            // If we didn't find the body in the last parts, 
            // let's loop for the first parts (text-html only)
            if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
                foreach ($parts  as $part) {
                    if($part['body'] && $part['mimeType'] === 'text/html') {
                        $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($part['body']->data);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // With no attachment, the payload might be directly in the body, encoded.
            if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
                $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($body['data']);
            }
            // Last try: if we didn't find the body in the last parts, 
            // let's loop for the first parts (text-plain only)
            if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
                foreach ($parts  as $part) {
                    if($part['body']) {
                        $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($part['body']->data);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
                $FOUND_BODY = '(No message)';
            }
            // Finally, print the message ID and the body
            print_r($message_id . ": " . $FOUND_BODY);
        }

        if ($list->getNextPageToken() != null) {
            $pageToken = $list->getNextPageToken();
            $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', ['pageToken' => $pageToken, 'maxResults' => 1000]);
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Cheers.

Comment: Works perfrectly fine for all kind of attachments but not for jpg or jpeg. Bmp are downloaded fine though. Could you please help??

Comment: Actually I have no problem to display all types of images which are located in the *body* of the email. For those which are located in the attachments you might want to loop on the $payload->getParts(). Maybe it's your problem here?

Comment: The body works perfectly fine. So I need to apply the $payload->getParts() iteration??  Can you provide additional help please?

Comment: It looks like I forgot to add a line about the parts in the code above (I've juste edited it).
If it's still not working, I'll add the code for retrieving the attachments, just let me know if it's necessary.

Comment: I gave it a shot but it does not seem to work with jpegs and jpg images. I have a question though; why all other attachments like pdf, mov mp4 files are downloaded show up correct?

Comment: You cannot display .pdf, .mov or .mp4 in the body of your emails - nor retrieving it with my current code, can you?

Comment: No I can't. But somehow I have managed to get the content and store it as a base64 string. Combined with the headers, I get the files correctly

Comment: I owe you a beer!! Outstanding code! Absolutely perfect!

Comment: This is a great solution! Flawlessly finds the body in a different array of situations! thanks!

Comment: i just try to get max result 5, in my network tab it loaded for 40+ MB still loading no vales are fetched

Comment: @Eibs, yes because there is a loop `while ($list->getMessages() != null) {`. You need to remove it, if you only want 5 last messages.

Comment: @F3L1X79 do you have whole gmail api mailbox code sample? if you have this kindly share the repository link please?

Comment: No sorry, I'm not working with PHP anymore

Answer (score 13):

I wrote this code as an improvement of @[F3L1X79](https://stackoverflow.com/users/3933603/f3l1x79)'s answer as this filters html response correctly.

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", 1);
ini_set("track_errors", 1);
ini_set("html_errors", 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);
require_once __DIR__ . '/vendor/autoload.php';

session_start();

function decodeBody($body) {
    $rawData = $body;
    $sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
    $decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);
    if(!$decodedMessage){
        $decodedMessage = FALSE;
    }
    return $decodedMessage;
}

function fetchMails($gmail, $q) {

try{
    $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', array('q' => $q));
    while ($list->getMessages() != null) {

        foreach ($list->getMessages() as $mlist) {

            $message_id = $mlist->id;
            $optParamsGet2['format'] = 'full';
            $single_message = $gmail->users_messages->get('me', $message_id, $optParamsGet2);
            $payload = $single_message->getPayload();

            // With no attachment, the payload might be directly in the body, encoded.
            $body = $payload->getBody();
            $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($body['data']);

            // If we didn't find a body, let's look for the parts
            if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
                $parts = $payload->getParts();
                foreach ($parts  as $part) {
                    if($part['body'] && $part['mimeType'] == 'text/html') {
                        $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($part['body']->data);
                        break;
                    }
                }
            } if(!$FOUND_BODY) {
                foreach ($parts  as $part) {
                    // Last try: if we didn't find the body in the first parts, 
                    // let's loop into the parts of the parts (as @Tholle suggested).
                    if($part['parts'] && !$FOUND_BODY) {
                        foreach ($part['parts'] as $p) {
                            // replace 'text/html' by 'text/plain' if you prefer
                            if($p['mimeType'] === 'text/html' && $p['body']) {
                                $FOUND_BODY = decodeBody($p['body']->data);
                                break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                    if($FOUND_BODY) {
                        break;
                    }
                }
            }
            // Finally, print the message ID and the body
            print_r($message_id . " <br> <br> <br> *-*-*- " . $FOUND_BODY);
        }

        if ($list->getNextPageToken() != null) {
            $pageToken = $list->getNextPageToken();
            $list = $gmail->users_messages->listUsersMessages('me', array('pageToken' => $pageToken));
        } else {
            break;
        }
    }
} catch (Exception $e) {
    echo $e->getMessage();
}

}

$client = new Google_Client();
$client->setAuthConfig('client_secrets.json');
$client->addScope(Google_Service_Gmail::GMAIL_READONLY);

if (isset($_SESSION['access_token']) && $_SESSION['access_token']) {
    $client->setAccessToken($_SESSION['access_token']);
    $gmail = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
    $q = ' after:2016/11/7';
    fetchMails($gmail, $q);
} else {
    $redirect_uri = 'http://' . $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . '/gmail-api/oauth2callback.php';
    header('Location: ' . filter_var($redirect_uri, FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
}
```

Comment: This is the most comprehensive solution for the problem.

Comment: Can anybody help me. Im using this url $endpoint = "https://www.googleapis.com/gmail/v1/users/me/messages/$id?format=full"; but its only getting 194 characters in an email not the full email. what can i do?

Comment: format=full is the default, you don't need to send it. Try without, do you get a different result? Also, probably better to put this in a separate question! :-)

Answer (score 13):

## A simple, ROBUST solution

I wasn't satisfied with the other answers because they're all flawed (elaboration in spoiler), and some are long and mixed with features the asker (and I) didn't look for.

> To warn you about potential problems in other answers:
>  no plain text fallback
>  or failing to deal with [falsy](https://php.net/manual/en/language.types.boolean.php#language.types.boolean.casting) message body - the string '0' (unlikely to happen, but not too unlikely)
>  or lacking a deep enough search through the payload tree structure

So I thought I'd save others the trouble and share my code (tested on my entire inbox).

```
// input: the message object (not the payload!)
// output: html or plain text
function msg_body($msg) {
   $body = msg_body_recursive($msg->payload);
   return array_key_exists('html', $body) ? $body['html'] : $body['plain'];
}

function msg_body_recursive($part) {
   if($part->mimeType == 'text/html') {
      return ['html' => decodeBody($part->body->data)];
   } else if($part->mimeType == 'text/plain') {
      return ['plain' => decodeBody($part->body->data)];
   } else if($part->parts) {
      $return = [];
      foreach($part->parts as $sub_part) {
         $result = msg_body_recursive($sub_part);
         $return = array_merge($return, $result);
         if(array_key_exists('html', $return))
            break;
      }
      return $return;
   }
   return [];
}

function decodeBody($encoded) {
   $sanitizedData = strtr($encoded,'-_', '+/');
   return base64_decode($sanitizedData);
}
```

Comment: This is the best answer.  Thank you

Comment: I tested the other solutions and this works best. Make sure you pass it something like this:  $service->users_messages->get('me', $message->getId()); It took me a while to figure it out. The other solutions worked in 80% of cases but failed when the object had sub-parts. Many thanks @potato.

Comment: This was exactly what I needed and I like the fact that it's short and sweet.

Comment: I just found another mime type today. came here just to share: `text/x-amp-html`

Answer (score 0):

As further improvement the code should be recursive, also you need to load the message in format "full" to extract the body. Below three functions you can put into your own class.

```
private function decodeBody($body) {
    $rawData = $body;
    $sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
    $decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);
    if(!$decodedMessage)
        return false;

    return $decodedMessage;
}

private function decodeParts($parts)
{
    foreach ($parts as $part)
    {
        if ($part->getMimeType() === 'text/html' && $part->getBody())
            if ($result = $this->decodeBody($part->getBody()->getData()))
                return $result;
    }

    foreach ($parts as $part)
    {
        if ($result = $this->decodeParts($part->getParts()))
            return $result;
    }
}

/**
 * @param Google_Service_Gmail_Message $message
 * @return bool|null|string
 */
public function getMessageBody($message)
{
    $payload = $message->getPayload();
    if ($result = $this->decodeBody($payload->getBody()->getData()))
        return $result;

    return $this->decodeParts($payload->getParts());
}
```

Comment: Can you put this in context of an example?

Comment: @dearsina Sorry you are right. The answer was missing one function. I just updated it. You can copy them to your own class and just call `getMessageBody()`.

Answer (score 0):

I just want to complement @F3L1X79 answer, before you break de foreach loop, you have to check the $FOUND_BODY variable is not FALSE, so I added an If condition before every break; in the body search. If you don't do this, the code wil break even if the body was not found.

```
if($FOUND_BODY !== false) break;
```