# How do I read the mail body from Gmail API using PHP?

Tags: php, google-api, gmail, google-api-php-client, gmail-api

in witch mode a can read the  Gmail ApI email body with PHP.

```
$client = getClient();
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$user = 'me';
$results = $service->users_messages->listUsersMessages($user);
$messageId = $results[0]->getId();
$optParamsGet = array();
$optParamsGet['format'] = full;
$message = $service->users_messages->get('me',$messageId,$optParamsGet);
```

What do I need to do next?

I tried print_r of the $message Array I don't understand where is the body.

Comment: Uh, what? could you perhaps rephrase your question?

Comment: sorry i just edit the message . it's better?

Comment: [This question is somewhat related](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655874/cannot-get-the-body-of-email-with-gmail-php-api/32660892#32660892)

Comment: yes it's Correct ! i use this answer : http://stackoverflow.com/a/32669447/3766637