# Gmail RESTAPI how to fetch the message body for any mime type message through gmail php api?

Tags: gmail, gmail-api, incoming-mail

I am working on a project to retrieve the gmail inbox messages through GMAIL REST API and populate them into a new user interface that is going to be used for other purpose. This project is in PHP. I am currently using PHP version. This is the code snippet that I am using to retrieve the message body.

```
$service = new Google_Service_Gmail($client);
$user = 'me';
    function get_Message_Body($messageId,$service)
    {
        $optParamsGet = [];
        $optParamsGet['format'] = 'full';
        echo "this is optParamsGet";
        var_dump($optParamsGet);
        $message = $service->users_messages->get('me',$messageId,$optParamsGet);
        echo "this is message";
        var_dump($message);
        echo "<pre>".$message->snippet."</pre>";
        $messagePayload = $message->getPayload();
        $headers = $message->getPayload()->getHeaders();
        $parts = $message->getPayload()->getParts();
        $body = $parts[0]['body'];
        echo "this is body";
        var_dump($body);
        $rawData = $body->data;
        $sanitizedData = strtr($rawData,'-_', '+/');
        $decodedMessage = base64_decode($sanitizedData);
        echo $decodedMessage;
    }

    get_Message_Body($_REQUEST["id"], $service);
```

However, I see that this code works only for messages with mime/type of multipart/alternative. However, I need to retrieve the message body and attachments for any kind of gmail message. How do I do that. This is the output that I see for a different mime type on the new user interface 
[The code snippet for retrieving the messages](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zwFRa.png)

Here the message body in the snippet, does not pass into the data parameter in the MessagePartBody. Unlike this code which is mime type mulipart/alternative, where the code passes into the message body->parts and rendered on ui.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AI8a6.png)

Comment: [This](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655874/cannot-get-the-body-of-email-with-gmail-php-api/32660892#32660892) might give some clues.

Comment: What does this have to do with Google Maps?

Comment: Thank you for responding @Tholle. I do not know why it does not work with the code http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655874/cannot-get-the-body-of-email-with-gmail-php-api/32660892#32660892

Comment: The solution http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655874/cannot-get-the-body-of-email-with-gmail-php-api/32660892#32660892 works. Thank you @Tholle

Comment: @SwethaNaidu Sweet! No problem.