# Gmail API - getParts() returning null for yahoo messages

Tags: gmail-api

When reading email sent from an yahoo account, the method message.getPayload().getParts() returns null. Tested it with other domains (gmail, outlook, hotmail) and had no problem.

In fact, getPayload() returns a string without the "parts" field.

Any ideas?

Thanks.

Edit:

I'm using Java.

And that's an example of the raw message:

```
Delivered-To: ...@gmail.com
Received: by 10.25.38.80 with SMTP id m77csp2082720lfm;
        Wed, 23 Aug 2017 11:21:52 -0700 (PDT)
X-Received: by 10.36.88.19 with SMTP id f19mr3619353itb.114.1503512512655;
        Wed, 23 Aug 2017 11:21:52 -0700 (PDT)
ARC-Seal: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; t=1503512512; cv=none;
        d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        b=hNlRtyLieEAxck27i5zZez/QG7M98ZOJjAHmzvMHPs/ON5G3TvtKm5IQ4SWxGef1bu
         pMLtqt3u3ti8EmOoaGvIsWF8fkCEYWJNyTrm+AfVBIW/vWcaBO5C+/gU/2l8c1bz640/
         cjGyUkfYH5P7eaA8Bn5qJqbGC6RN0jH99qP0keLCCXDEtD15pNUqWvlRy2cYthvxrApX
         gwmB5RGoDHJxWym97ULj2jbXU8d2msM2oCTKsGKAYPfPUKxpmU9omE1fAPSd+0a2UuGo
         qXviZ6r9ZOoj2UYeCulbLe2c8OaKXSPYT+j6OGSRQ/9KkM7122Mo3U7B30WdSm0steTO
         cOPg==
ARC-Message-Signature: i=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=google.com; s=arc-20160816;
        h=references:content-transfer-encoding:mime-version:subject
         :message-id:to:reply-to:from:date:dkim-signature
         :arc-authentication-results;
        bh=Tz5JmALH26W2NmpUut1b8KAtYumw1nslUgD+V4O7niU=;
        b=GACDabh89djjl0DusVFNR6mcyoStwHcH311IyqNkxC/rAipc9kIVjaxJHetooodQ4/
         TKBVH4N2mfLpeQSr0sFHILcnJWklC8K9ZMI11GVC1KMcvr0sdfSLBXZ2xXxkBq2aM/F9
         1AmCJ3dLwsn6n7qoFUPKukpt1dJWTmU9OdWq2rdw5477Ol7ieXnnC2SX3K7GyD1fKDjV
         /Skj6Q+vKDuNUzexuh1V4zTcuuAUM03VlG/gbrFjPrp3ABvnlzuV1/8nu4QdQte/h3Cz
         HJUOikVOQHm7HPTHJQi91639k3/Nl/TvC8bPpWF56CwRxBfMTtRZDHJAzjymOqYNjndM
         PL5g==
ARC-Authentication-Results: i=1; mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@yahoo.com header.s=s2048 header.b=n8P3/tJJ;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of ...@yahoo.com designates 66.163.190.61 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=...@yahoo.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=yahoo.com
Return-Path: <...@yahoo.com>
Received: from sonic307-38.consmr.mail.ne1.yahoo.com (sonic307-38.consmr.mail.ne1.yahoo.com. [66.163.190.61])
        by mx.google.com with ESMTPS id c132si2139994itc.196.2017.08.23.11.21.52
        for <...@gmail.com>
        (version=TLS1_2 cipher=ECDHE-RSA-AES128-GCM-SHA256 bits=128/128);
        Wed, 23 Aug 2017 11:21:52 -0700 (PDT)
Received-SPF: pass (google.com: domain of ...@yahoo.com designates 66.163.190.61 as permitted sender) client-ip=66.163.190.61;
Authentication-Results: mx.google.com;
       dkim=pass header.i=@yahoo.com header.s=s2048 header.b=n8P3/tJJ;
       spf=pass (google.com: domain of ...@yahoo.com designates 66.163.190.61 as permitted sender) smtp.mailfrom=...@yahoo.com;
       dmarc=pass (p=REJECT sp=REJECT dis=NONE) header.from=yahoo.com
DKIM-Signature: v=1; a=rsa-sha256; c=relaxed/relaxed; d=yahoo.com; s=s2048; t=1503512512; bh=Tz5JmALH26W2NmpUut1b8KAtYumw1nslUgD+V4O7niU=; h=Date:From:Reply-To:To:Subject:References:From:Subject; b=n8P3/tJJ46TZtkbxEu9p93hHodloAc938JlVtFNggsFDKOh1CXeELNzqwZpx2RpnlxKLg0mMIrSO+6ixFI2jQXpI2OEkMjMW+Lojz2f6MDRzktI24qeoHK6z0OODwEr13l8+NRFuvEgatiOoKG4nK/0ESYRYj6MK2580zYFdMO34vdAUKwS5c7+T7cNTbb2Ov3+zNP+kHVOnFTpxcYKeRvqnueRbJMAgu/zqNEb5uptfny/uv96oSj0qampNulxjw3RM+rXzGnDhzex/dKS3aKUxkaTA/C1Y/pK88Arp14BYh5SUwlY1IM8+ae/gFFYHQmcN4tD99+f6QZkL+U+nDA==
X-YMail-OSG: bU76A0cVM1mKMrarfFd.RRvN1pJLGQPGtympfd4w.3r6YP1PfmogV2hMIGfIjW3
 p3.MJ5enUkT9dmftCW24yuYPZH4MhX2BJCXOQBBjVdpf4n7AWMev2Lg2V1l_yh9aivYy3lyFz2mp
 E7B7QicUKsBZsDrLKZy6aj1p1SKMXTK2BaM1FLvw7geXcSVImhw8xoWaTjWwXgrTrKmZv4xl9Lfn
 J17mHtiuK_aFBVuPTbneEqxexfSgqN.mZCJzHZYFUAOeU3U3dfVEYVxG8ohJK.rUNxEj2EgXdCg2
 FZq.xcE.R9_.ghSDSm5GH3G2BkpEEQ95VGAyPXfhEmZMLDKf08zx5_6FM_npwflAYYnnlLNYDJ0j
 bvuKIfPljJunLWdxSQvx3_RsKdlFrBXXR1umg41QuqzXlZs4C8FQBdgzNwPrhuGU_NoPKf.MAhCW
 rJmi9RcDFfNENxetttsECz9TvDacjN3.Ij3z6cf3oVkKVNTM8coPQpv5iEYUtQ0PRt3Iay.g.dg-
 -
Received: from sonic.gate.mail.ne1.yahoo.com by sonic307.consmr.mail.ne1.yahoo.com with HTTP; Wed, 23 Aug 2017 18:21:52 +0000
Date: Wed, 23 Aug 2017 18:17:51 +0000 (UTC)
From: ... <...@yahoo.com>
Reply-To: ... <...@yahoo.com>
To: "...@gmail.com" <...@gmail.com>
Message-ID: <843172102.808351.1503512271497@mail.yahoo.com>
Subject: =?UTF-8?Q?[Sala_de_semin=C3=A1rios]?=
MIME-Version: 1.0
Content-Type: text/plain; charset=UTF-8
Content-Transfer-Encoding: quoted-printable
References: <843172102.808351.1503512271497.ref@mail.yahoo.com>
X-Mailer: WebService/1.1.10451 YahooMailNeo Mozilla/5.0 (X11; Linux x86_64; rv:55.0) Gecko/20100101 Firefox/55.0
Content-Length: 53

Data: 01/01/1970
Hora: 11:30
Dura=C3=A7=C3=A3o: 00:30
```

Comment: The `payload` is the only part in some `text/plain` messages. What does the entire `raw` message look like?

Comment: @Tholle I've updated my question to include the raw message.

Comment: Great. The `payload` is indeed the only `part` in the message in your question. Maybe you could get some inspiration from [**this answer**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655874/cannot-get-the-body-of-email-with-gmail-php-api/32660892#32660892), even though the algorithm is written in JavaScript.

Answer (score 0):

[This information](https://www.phpclasses.org/blog/package/2/post/2-Retrieving-email-messages-using-PHP-from-Gmail-Hotmail-and-Yahoo-via-POP3.html) might help. It appears there's a restriction in using Yahoo Mail unlike other domains.

**Yahoo! Mail**

> Currently, accessing Yahoo! Mail mailbox messages via POP3 is
>   restricted to paying users of the Yahoo! Mail plus service. Other than
>   that, most parameters are similar to Gmail and Hotmail, except that
>   the user name should be just the account user name, thus without the @
>   character and the domain name.

```
$pop3 = new pop3_class;
 $pop3->hostname = "pop.mail.yahoo.com";
 $pop3->port = 995;
 $pop3->tls = 1;
 $user = "account";
 $password = "account password";
```