# How can I get the body of an email with Python and Google's gmail API?

Tags: python, email, google-api, gmail-api

I just started up with APIs and figured I'd play around with Gmail's.  I'm looking to scrape all emails sent to me in the past month for some text analysis.  I might just be being thick here or have missed some documentation somewhere (probably), but I can't figure out how to get the body of emails that had attachments.  I'm not interested in the attachment, just the body of the email.

```
results = gmail.users().messages().list(labelIds=['INBOX'], q='to:me after: '+str(date),userId='me').execute()
mssg_list = results['messages']
for mssg in mssg_list:
    m_id = mssg['id']
    message = gmail.users().messages().get(userId='me', id=m_id).execute()
    body = message['payload']['parts'][1]['body']
    final_body = base64.urlsafe_b64decode(body['data'].decode("utf-8"))
```

For messages with attachments, it returns only attachmentId and size, rather than size and data.  I tried reading the attachmentId to see if perhaps data was kept there instead, but no dice; it appears to just refer to the attachment.   Where is the actual text body living?

Comment: Bit offtopic: raw ``except``s are almost never a good idea. Better only catch the exception you might expect and let all the other, rather unexpected ones raise.

Comment: Thanks--good point.  I don't anticipate keeping the except; I'll remove to eliminate any potential confusion.

Comment: Have you stumbled upon [**this question**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655874/cannot-get-the-body-of-email-with-gmail-php-api/32660892#32660892)? It is a PHP question, and the example algorithm is written in JavaScript, but it might be of some help.