# read gmail message body with the object com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message in java?

Tags: java, google-api, mime, gmail-api, google-api-client

I'm trying to read gmail message using GmailAPI. I successfully got the message object.

I've the object `com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message` and its .toString() resulting 
`{"id":"157433a7e******","threadId":"157433a7e******"}`

But i'm unable to read the contents of the object `message.getPayload()` is returning null, `.getSnippet()` is returning null, `.getRaw()` is also returning null

Object API : https://developers.google.com/resources/api-libraries/documentation/gmail/v1/java/latest/com/google/api/services/gmail/model/Message.html

I've tried other ways as mentioned in

[How to get full message body in Gmail?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28026099/how-to-get-full-message-body-in-gmail/38828761)

I want to know the `mail subject, dates, sender, label, body`

Can some one gives me any pointer?

This is the project source I'm using

`com.google.api-client %% google-api-client %% 1.22.0`

`com.google.oauth-client %% google-oauth-client-jetty %% 1.22.0`

`com.google.apis %% google-api-services-gmail %% v1-rev48-1.22.0`

Thanks In Advance

Answer (score 3):

If you try the [API Explorer for listing messages](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/list#try-it), you will see that the response only contains an `id` of the message and a `threadId`. You have to make an additional request to [get the content of the message](https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get#try-it).

```
Message test = service.users().messages().get("me", "157433a7e******").setFormat("full").execute();
```

Then you just have to get the fields from the message and [traverse the parts to get the content of the message](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32655874/cannot-get-the-body-of-email-with-gmail-php-api/32660892#32660892).