# How to retrieve the email body content with Gmail API?

Tags: java, google-api, gmail, gmail-api, google-api-java-client

I'm studying Gmail API. Let's say I'm interested to see which mail contains the string "foobar2000".

This is my code so far:

Main.java

```
package manhattan.email.bot;

import com.google.api.client.googleapis.javanet.GoogleNetHttpTransport;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.MessagePart;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.UnsupportedEncodingException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.security.GeneralSecurityException;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;

import manhattan.email.bot.google.GmailCredentials;
import manhattan.email.bot.google.GmailService;
import manhattan.email.bot.google.GmailServiceImpl;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.Base64;
import org.apache.commons.codec.binary.StringUtils;

public class Main {

    static final String MY_EMAIL = "xxxxx@gmail.com";
    static final String MY_CLIENT_ID = "xxxxxapps.googleusercontent.com";    
    static final String MY_CLIENT_SECRET = "xxxxx";
    static final String MY_ACCESS_TOKEN = "xxxxx";
    static final String MY_REFRESH_TOKEN = "xxxxx";

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        try {
            GmailService gmailService = new GmailServiceImpl(GoogleNetHttpTransport.newTrustedTransport());
            gmailService.setGmailCredentials(GmailCredentials.builder()
                    .userEmail(MY_EMAIL)
                    .clientId(MY_CLIENT_ID)
                    .clientSecret(MY_CLIENT_SECRET)
                    .accessToken(MY_ACCESS_TOKEN)
                    .refreshToken(MY_REFRESH_TOKEN)
                    .build());

           List<com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message> messageList = gmailService.listMessagesMatchingQuery(MY_EMAIL,"foobar2000");
           System.out.println("Search result: ");

           for (Message m:messageList){
               System.out.println(m.toPrettyString());
            }

        }
        catch (GeneralSecurityException gse){
            System.err.println(">>> GSE: "+gse.getMessage());
        }
        catch (IOException ioe){
            System.err.println(">>> IOE: "+ioe.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

GmailCredentials.java

```
package manhattan.email.bot.google;

import lombok.Builder;
import lombok.Data;

@Builder
@Data
public class GmailCredentials {
    private final String userEmail;
    private final String clientId;
    private final String clientSecret;
    private final String accessToken;
    private final String refreshToken;
}
```

GmailService.java

```
package manhattan.email.bot.google;

import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.List;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;

public interface GmailService {

    void setGmailCredentials(GmailCredentials credentials);
    boolean sendMessage(String recipientAddress, String subject, String body) throws MessagingException, IOException;
    List<Message> listMessagesMatchingQuery(String userId, String query) throws IOException; 
}
```

GmailServiceImpl.java

```
package manhattan.email.bot.google;

import com.google.api.client.auth.oauth2.Credential;
import com.google.api.client.googleapis.auth.oauth2.GoogleCredential;
import com.google.api.client.http.HttpTransport;
import com.google.api.client.json.JsonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.json.jackson2.JacksonFactory;
import com.google.api.client.util.Base64;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.Gmail;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.ListMessagesResponse;
import com.google.api.services.gmail.model.Message;
import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Properties;
import javax.mail.MessagingException;
import javax.mail.Session;
import javax.mail.internet.InternetAddress;
import javax.mail.internet.MimeMessage;

/**
 *
 * @author OCIN
 */
public class GmailServiceImpl implements GmailService {

    private static final String APPLICATION_NAME = "mail-bot";
    private static final JsonFactory JSON_FACTORY = JacksonFactory.getDefaultInstance();

    private final HttpTransport httpTransport;
    private GmailCredentials gmailCredentials;

    public GmailServiceImpl(HttpTransport transport){
        this.httpTransport = transport;
    }

    private Gmail createGmail() {
        Credential credential = authorize();
        return new Gmail.Builder(httpTransport, JSON_FACTORY, credential)
                .setApplicationName(APPLICATION_NAME)
                .build();
    }

     private Credential authorize() {
        return new GoogleCredential.Builder()
                .setTransport(httpTransport)
                .setJsonFactory(JSON_FACTORY)
                .setClientSecrets(gmailCredentials.getClientId(), gmailCredentials.getClientSecret())
                .build()
                .setAccessToken(gmailCredentials.getAccessToken())
                .setRefreshToken(gmailCredentials.getRefreshToken());
    }

    @Override
    public void setGmailCredentials(GmailCredentials credentials) {
        this.gmailCredentials = credentials;
    }

     private MimeMessage createEmail(String to, String from, String subject, String bodyText) throws MessagingException {
        MimeMessage email = new MimeMessage(Session.getDefaultInstance(new Properties(), null));
        email.setFrom(new InternetAddress(from));
        email.addRecipient(javax.mail.Message.RecipientType.TO, new InternetAddress(to));
        email.setSubject(subject);
        email.setText(bodyText);
        return email;
    }

    private Message createMessageWithEmail(MimeMessage emailContent) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        ByteArrayOutputStream buffer = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
        emailContent.writeTo(buffer);

        return new Message().setRaw(Base64.encodeBase64URLSafeString(buffer.toByteArray()));
    }

    @Override
    public boolean sendMessage(String recipientAddress, String subject, String body) throws MessagingException, IOException {
        Message message = createMessageWithEmail(
            createEmail(recipientAddress, gmailCredentials.getUserEmail(), subject, body));

        return createGmail().users()
            .messages()
            .send(gmailCredentials.getUserEmail(), message)
            .execute()
            .getLabelIds().contains("SENT");
    }

    public List<Message> listMessagesMatchingQuery(String userId, String query) throws IOException {
        ListMessagesResponse response = createGmail().users().messages().list(userId).setQ(query).execute();
        List<Message> messages = new ArrayList<Message>();

        while (response.getMessages() != null) {
            messages.addAll(response.getMessages());
            if (response.getNextPageToken() != null) {
                String pageToken = response.getNextPageToken();
                response = createGmail().users().messages().list(userId).setQ(query).setPageToken(pageToken).execute();
            } 
            else {
                break;
            }
        }

       // for (Message message : messages) {
       //     System.out.println(message.toPrettyString());
       // }

        return messages;
    }
}
```

The output of my code is:

> Search result: 
>   {   "id" : "16d929a8524a6bbd",   "threadId" : "16d929a8524a6bbd" }

Which is true, because there's only 1 mail with "foobar2000" in the body. The full body content is:

> Bla bla bla
>   foobar2000
>   Hello world

How to get that?
I tried using this inside the loop:

```
System.out.println(StringUtils.newStringUtf8(Base64.decodeBase64(m.getPayload().getParts().get(0).getBody().getData())));
```

Gave me a NullPointerException...

Comment: I understand that the error only appears on the last piece of code that you posted. There are many methods chained together, so I strongly recommend to divide them and log them all step by step; starting from the `m` itself until the `newStringUtf8`. That way we all can see clearly where the `NullPointerException` comes from. Another approach is to save the message ID to use the `messages.get` [ https://developers.google.com/gmail/api/v1/reference/users/messages/get ] method.

Comment: After some debugging... I found that `m.getPayload()` returns null. So this is the cause of NPE. Hmm...

Comment: Interestingly, `m.getSnippet()` returns this: `Message snippet: Bla bla bla foobar2000 Hello world -- Clive Stevenson Android Developer M: +62 822 44 5555 E: clive.stevenson@test123.com South Jakarta, Indonesia.
Bla bla bla foobar2000 Hello world -- Clive Stevenson Android Developer M: +62 822 44 5555 E: clive.stevenson@test123.com South Jakarta, Indonesia.` The content I'm looking for is `Bla bla bla foobar2000 Hello world`. How to get that?

Answer (score 2):

If I understood your situation well, you said on your last comment, `m.getSnippet()` gives you back this text:

```
Message snippet: Bla bla bla foobar2000 Hello world -- Clive Stevenson Android Developer M: +62 822 44 5555 E: clive.stevenson@test123.com South Jakarta, Indonesia.
```

And you want to end up only with the message body:

```
Bla bla bla foobar2000 Hello world
```

If that is your situation, you can use the following function to end up with the message body:

```
public String getContent(Message message) {
    StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
    try {
        getPlainTextFromMessageParts(message.getPayload().getParts(), stringBuilder);
        byte[] bodyBytes = Base64.decodeBase64(stringBuilder.toString());
        String text = new String(bodyBytes, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
        return text;
    } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e) {
        logger.error("UnsupportedEncoding: " + e.toString());
        return message.getSnippet();
    }
}

private void getPlainTextFromMessageParts(List<MessagePart> messageParts, StringBuilder stringBuilder) {
    for (MessagePart messagePart : messageParts) {
        if (messagePart.getMimeType().equals("text/plain")) {
            stringBuilder.append(messagePart.getBody().getData());
        }

        if (messagePart.getParts() != null) {
            getPlainTextFromMessageParts(messagePart.getParts(), stringBuilder);
        }
    }
}
```

That code will extract the body as you requested. Please, let me know if you need further clarifications or you need more help.

Kudos to [Gerard Verbeek](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38828761) for sharing the previous code.

Comment: ty, works great! I did decoding this way: Base64 base64Url = new Base64(true); String bodyDecoded = StringUtils.newStringUtf8( base64Url.decodeBase64( stringBuilder.toString() ));